# An Unhandled win32 exception occured in tst.exe with visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to execute an .exe using visual studio 2012, it will be crashing with a message   An Unhandled win32 exception occured in tst.exe. If i try too debug it says,

Unhandled exception at 0x0000000077CB2F86 (ntdll.dll) in tst01301.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFFFFFFFFF20886A8.

Please suggest me with a solution.

Comment: Debug the program. Start by finding out what it's doing when it encounters the exception.

Comment: You have a bug in your program, use a debugger. If you want help from here, you have to post the code of your program.

Comment: Fix the access violation. Nearly 100% reduction in errors like this when you follow that through.

Comment: How to find the .exe debug OR release versions

Comment: Am debugging the simple program in vs 2012, printf("hello");    fflush(stdout);<-------crahing statement--------->